# Image Gallery control not loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image-gallery, devexpress-mvc

I am currently working on a project that has decided to incorporate Image Gallery from DevExpress MVC.  Previously when put into the page, we had an bug come up where if the SettingsFullscreenViewer.Visible was set true, you could not upload.  However, once turned to false, we could upload and do whatever on development.

We pushed to our testing site and discovered now we get the following error: "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.'"  It only fires when there is an image within the Image Gallery for that particular item.  The thumbnails of the image just sit there and spin.

I am somewhat at a loss and was curious if anyone else has had issues with this control also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  The issue was that my ImageCacheFolder was trying to create itself but did not have permissions.  Once I added permissions to the particular folder I had for uploads, the issue went away.